# Image upload to s3 does not render

Tags: reactjs, react-native, amazon-s3, axios, expo

I am using Expo Image Picker to send a cropped image to s3. The file is being uploaded, but it does not render as an image as its not recognised as one. If I took the blob data and use it in a base64 to image encoder I get the image, so it must be mime or encoding based, here is what I have.

I invoke the Expo Image Picker with;

```
let pickerResult = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
  allowsEditing: true,
  aspect: [1, 1],
  base64: true,
  exif: false,
});
```

The params I use to create the signed URL from s3 SDK are;

```
const params = {
    Bucket: 'images,
    Key: 'filename.jpg',
    Expires: 60 * 5,
    ACL: 'public-read',
    ContentEncoding: 'base64',
    ContentType: 'image/jpeg'
};
```

The upload is done with axios with the following headers;

```
const config = { 
                  headers: {
                    'x-amz-acl' : 'public-read', 
                    'Content-Encoding': 'base64',
                    'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'
                  }
                };

return await axios.put(`${signedURL}`,
  base64data,
  config)
    .then(response => {
      console.log('IMAGE UPLOAD SUCCESS');
      return response.data;
    })
```

If I change the created .jpg file as .txt and view it in sublime the data is the base64 encoded string rather than the usual blob data of a jpeg.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok; found the solution;

use the buffer npm module;

import { Buffer } from 'buffer';

Added this to my function

```
return await axios.put(`${signedURL}`,
      new Buffer(base64data, 'base64'), // make this a buffer
      config)
        .then(response => {
          console.log('IMAGE UPLOAD SUCCESS');
          return response.data;
        })
```